# How do I safely lock an ASP.NET MVC3 Session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, concurrency, session-state

I want to modify the Session variable in an ASP.NET MVC3 Controller (that has SessionState required) in a thread-safe manner. What object should I lock on?